# Disable a link when already on the page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a list(ul) which when click you will be redirected to another page, what I want to do is disable the clickable link when you are already on that page and also, have it highlighted.

```
<div class="selection">
<ul>
  <li><a href="name">Name</a></li>
  <li><a href="comments">Comments</a></li>
</ul>
```

TYIA!

Comment: Are you hand-coding those links? I would think you would use `link_to`. In which case, you could use `link_to_unless_current` to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [**`current_page?`**](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F)

```
<ul>
  <% if current_page?('/name') %>
    <li><strong>Name</strong></li>
  <% else %>
    <li><a href="name">Name</a></li>
  <% end %>
  <% if current_page?('/comments') %>
    <li><strong>Comments</strong></li>
  <% else %>
    <li><a href="comments">Comments</a></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'll try. Thanks for the recommendation :)

Comment: on the second if statement, is it really "(/name)" or "(/comments?)"

Comment: ahh. its "/comments" my bad

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery

HTML part

```
<div class="selection">
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="name">Name</a></li>
  <li><a href="comments">Comments</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#menu a").each(function(){
                //set all menu items to 'black
                $(this).css("color","black");

                var linkPath=$(this).attr("href");
                var relativePath=window.location.pathname.replace('http://'+window.location.hostname,'');

                //set the <a> with the same path as the current address to blue
                if(linkPath==relativePath)
                    $(this).css("color","blue");
            });
    });
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271329/how-can-i-give-the-current-pages-link-a-disabled-look)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a helper so you can use this on other parts, because you will need to.

```
def active_link(text, path)
  class_name = current_page?(path) ? 'active' : nil
  link_to text, path, :class => class_name
end
```

this will print a link with the class active if the link it's the same as the current page

```
active_link 'home', root_path
```

Now you can combine this with css so you can disable the click on the link when this have the active class

```
a.active {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

then with this all the links that you print with the helper will have the active class and with the css, this wouldn't have events on the click.

Answer (score -1):

after looking at your question, I think that the simplest answer to your solution while only utilizing html may be to get rid of the `<a>...</a>` tag on the source page so that when you're there, the text will show but is not linkable. As for having your text highlighted while on that page, use `<mark>...</mark>` as a child element of `<li>...</li>`.

An example, assuming that "name" is the active page:

```
<div class="selection">
    <ul>
      <li><mark>Name</mark></li>
      <li><a href="comments">Comments</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps a bit.